# What is the appropriate word to define the state of emotion in the following scenario?

Tags: word-choice, emotions

I was having dinner with my friend and all of a sudden my friend told me, "Oh my god, it is Good Friday and I am having chicken." He is Christian and he thinks it is not considered proper for a Catholic Christian to have a non-vegetarian meal on a holy day, but that's totally his choice. My question: What is a word for his "state of emotion(s)" when he uttered that particular sentence?
Is it proper if I say, "Why are you sad/upset/annoyed?"

Comment: If you can't recognize or put a name to the emotion you are observing, but you know it's bad, then ask, "What's the matter?"

Comment: I might call it ***panic-stricken***

Comment: Although, he can't be that serious of a Catholic if he "takes the Lord's name in vain."

Comment: @jim that's another thing we are n't here to talk about that.

Comment: yes i can say what's wrong or what happened but i want to know whether is any particular word for it

Comment: I'm just saying that his emotional state could range from "completely panic-stricken" because he believes he's just ruined his whole afterlife, to mild annoyance at realizing he's going to have to confess next week in church if he remembers to.  Tone of voice and color in the face might be used to disambiguate if we were actually there.  Because we weren't there we can only make educated guesses from the information we have.  And based on that information I'd say he's not really that upset just mildly annoyed.

Comment: There are many possible words for it but they would be selected based on the level of discomfort being observed.  And we don't know what that level is.  Hence we cannot provide an appropriate word.

Comment: What @Jim said. We really can't know exactly how our "lapsed Christian" views his "transgression" (it could be anything from a throwaway "witticism" to mortal terror that he's putting his immortal soul in jeopardy). It's not so much that all answers would be Primarily Opinion-based - more that the question is ***Unclear***, because it doesn't describe the way he feels in anything like sufficient detail.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If your friend is a Roman Catholic and you know he's just broken one of the rules for fast and abstinence, it wouldn't be appropriate to ask "Why are you upset?" because you already know the answer. You could cheer him up by saying "Well, you simply forgot. It can happen to anyone."

As for a word that describes his emotion, it largely depends on how deeply religious he is. It may range from mild "regret" to "guilt" or "shame".

Answer (score 0):

Let's do some fixing:

***I*** was having dinner with my friend and all of sudden my friend **said,** "**Oh,** my god, it is Good Friday and **I** am having chicken". He is **Christian** and he thinks it is not considered proper **for** a **Catholic** **Christian** to have **non-veg** on **a** holy day **, but** that's totally his choice. **M**y question is what is a word for his "state of emotions" when he uttered that particular sentence. **Is** it proper **to** say "**W**hy are you sad/upset/annoyed?"

"Upset" or "annoyed" seem fine to me.

Comment: *O* is a totally acceptable vocative particle. There's no reason to change it.

Answer (score 0):

It might vary. Punctuation might alter the word you should use here. As a religious man (him not me), I assume he is not used to eating non-vegan on holy days. If you had it with an exclamation mark at the end, it could have been:

> Surprised
>
> having or showing the feeling that people get when something unexpected or unusual happens : feeling or showing surprise

He is feeling surprised since he is experiencing something *unusual/unexpected*.
He is thinking why you are serving him non-vegan food on a holy day, in which he never does, I assume.

He may also be feeling some shame, guilt, and maybe some regret on coming here. He supposedly doesn't want to eat the meat here I assume. Shocked should also be a good word choice:

> Shock
>
> a sudden usually unpleasant or upsetting feeling caused by something unexpected

He doesn't expect this to happen is feeling rather upset and unpleasant because he is eating meat on a holy day when he isn't supposed to.

If the situation matches one of the two listed, yes, it is reasonable to ask the question. If he simply forgot, no, it isn't. Try to cheer him up if that's the case.

Answer (score 0):

I suggest **guilt-stricken**.

because the friend was suddenly struck by a feeling of guilt.

(I realize others have mentioned **guilt(y)** and **stricken**, but your scenario calls for the combo.)

Answer (score 0):

You might use "aghast" (somewhat archaic, strong, sounds humorous in many contexts today), or "flustered" (more "vintage" than archaic, also can sound a bit humorous).

"Mortified" might be your best bet if you're going for an old-fashioned, yet valid, description with a touch ofsome subtle dry humor.

Answer (score 0):

I would describe him as *chagrined*:

> a feeling of being frustrated or annoyed because of failure or disappointment <sub>(http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/chagrin)</sub>

or possibly *dismayed*:

> : a strong feeling of being worried, disappointed, or upset <sub>(http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/dismay)</sub>

In either case, it is not appropriate to ask "why are you upset", since he has just told you why.  :-)